How can I lower the number of qubits needed in a search algorithm?
I am trying to use quantum computing to iterate through an array with rows of 129 bits. So evidently I need 129 qubits. However, I am unable to simulate this amount of qubits on the qiskit Aer backend.Is there any way to lower this amount to like around 29 qubits (max amount of qubits in the simulation)? Should I decompose the search into smaller parts? So have about 5 diff searches using 29 qubits each?

Are you planning on doing a Grover algorithm? Or what is the "search" you are referring to? Is there any structure in the database you are searching? Do you know how many states you are looking for, or is there a guaranteed number of hits, respectively?
What won't work is splitting the qubits into 5 parts, and then repeating 5 times, this is not a linear relation.

Yes, this search is for the oracle of Grover's algorithm. I am searching through an array with many rows (5000 ish) that are 129 bits long. No there is not a guaranteed number of solution states that I am looking for. Can range from 0 to multiple. Why wouldn't that work? Is there another way? Thanks

Do I understand that correctly? You actually have 5000 states from which you are looking for 0, 1 or many states. I don't see what speaks against numbering the states 1,2,3,...,5000 and just use ~ 13 qubits for this problem

Constructing an oracle that does not make explicit use of the solution is however very non-trivial. Can you maybe provide some more information about the nature of your problem? What are you looking for exactly, how would you construct an oracle for 129 qubits? With this, one can try and reduce the problem to the 5000 states that you have.

To answer your last comment, each row has 129 bits, and I am looking to mark solution states (defined by a row with the LSB = 1 . However, your previous comment about numbering them from 1-5000 seems to be a great solution. Thanks for helping.
